# how to open link in webview in android similar to inappbrowser

Tags: java, android, webview

**here is my MainActivity.java code for displaying webview in my app**

```
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); /* xml layout file */
        wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
        webSettings.setSavePassword(true);
        webSettings.setSaveFormData(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(false);
```

/* this is my WebChromeClient code but its not working */

```
     wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return false;
            }
```

**how to fix it & make links open within webview
hope i have done everything correct**

Comment: Have you provided internet permissions in your Manifest file?

Comment: yup <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
i'm done with that but its not working

Comment: if i click any link its getting opened in default browser not in webview

Comment: Return true in shouldOverrideUrlLoading function instead of false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // enable javascript

final Activity activity = this;

 wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

wv.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

Also provide Internet permissions in your manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

If you overwrite shouldOverrideUrlLoading() function, can open within you webview as follow:

```
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.setClickable(true);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    boolean loadingFinished = true;
    boolean redirect = false;
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String urlNewString) {
        if (!loadingFinished) {
            redirect = true;
        }
        loadingFinished = false; 
        view.loadUrl(urlNewString);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap facIcon) {
        loadingFinished = false;
    }
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        if (!redirect) {
            loadingFinished = true;
        }
        if (loadingFinished && !redirect) {

           // loadingView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            redirect = false;
        }
    }
});
```